# Duplicate files while including butterknife with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

I have a basic Android app that I created with Android Studio, and I'm having problems adding butterknife to my build.  I get this error:

```
Error:: duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\apps\orion\app\build\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
    File 1: C:\Users\andres\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife\4.0.1\f43b36925363701633d01adb8e54df7150397a78\butterknife-4.0.1.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\andres\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife\4.0.1\f43b36925363701633d01adb8e54df7150397a78\butterknife-4.0.1.jar
```

My dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile project(':lib')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: FYI dagger-compiler should use the 'provided' scope for the dependency declaration.

Comment: This is one of those SO questions that have the wrong accepted answer. Listen to THE Jake Wharton!

Comment: @lemuel what? the accepted answer is by Xavier Ducrohet, who is the head of Android Tooling at Google

Comment: @AdamBurley I know who Xavier is. But look up Jake Wharton and Dagger, in the context of 2014. Also, look at how old this is. Also, look at the comments under Xavier Ducrohet's answer. I encountered this issue 7 years ago, and Nima G's answer was what worked.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Later versions of the plugin will tell you how to fix this. I think we introduced the fix in 0.8 so you should probably upgrade. Then the fix is to put this in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}
```

This will exclude this file from the packaging which is fine since it's not actually needed in the APK.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Could you tell me which plugin should I upgrade?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be fixed in gradle 0.8 unfortunately :-( This workaround is still required.

Comment: This is not a _workaround_. This is the normal solution. With 0.9.2 you can also decide to package the one of the file. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: I'm using 0.9 and still the same situation.

Comment: Version 1.2 reporting. Still no fix.

Answer (score 15):

That's because you wrote `compile` for `dagger-compiler`, replace it with `provided` and the issue will be fixed.

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
```

Comment: Instead of exclude and stuff this is the best answer !

Comment: So `apt` needs to be replaced with `provided`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you can use `apt` as well, but only for the compiler

Comment: @Nima Incidentally, Jack compiler in Android N sdk doesn't support `apt`.  See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203850

Answer (score 7):

The best option in version >= 0.9.1 of Gradle build tools is probably:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}
```

For more, see the Android Tools Project page: [New Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

Edit:
One last note here if you start having problems with generated code, make sure to structure your dependencies properly.  I ended up removing any exclusion of the Processor line and structuring my annotation processed dependencies like:

```
compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:0.2.15"
apt "org.parceler:parceler:0.2.15"
```

and

```
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

If after applying above given solutions you still face the same issue as I was, then if you are using **glide** library then change the version of the **glide** to it's max. 
eg.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```